# Java String to Byte Array Changes on Each Run

Tags: java, string, hash, byte

I'm having a strange problem with converting a string to a byte array to hash it. Right now, my code is something like this:

```
    String textToHash = "test"; 
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    messageDigest.update(textToHash.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    hash = messageDigest.digest();
```

Even though the string is the same, on different runs, the byte array (generated from `textToHash.getBytes("UTF-8")`) changes. Sometimes it will have one value, and other times it will change even though the string is static. Why is this happening and how can I make it reliably hash a string?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd think this has to be a case of "what you think is happening is not what is actually happening". String.getBytes should return the same thing for a given input string. What exactly leads you to believe that the input String is the same but that getBytes returns a different result?

Comment: My input string is always "test". When I print the value of `textToHash.getBytes`, it will sometimes return a different value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call MessageDigest.reset before update

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#reset()

Comment: That still doesn't work. It breaks before hashing. Essentially it's the getBytes call that's not working. The byte array that that produces is what varies. Not the output of the hash function.

Comment: @AndrewHassan sorry. Are you sure byte[] form for String.getBytes are different each time ? plz paste the testcase

Comment: I wasn't using any test cases, just debugging. If I print or view the value of the bytes, it will output different values from time to time. Here is one of my outputs:
`Test #0
String: test
Bytes: [B@68111f9b
Test #1
String: test
Bytes: [B@21c8dfe6
Test #2
String: test
Bytes: [B@ae3865e
Test #3
String: test
Bytes: [B@5f8a8ae7
Test #4
String: test
Bytes: [B@a574b2
Test #5
String: test
Bytes: [B@6e905272
Test #6
String: test
Bytes: [B@4514f313
Test #7
String: test
Bytes: [B@626287d3
Test #8
String: test
Bytes: [B@32c3601b
Test #9
String: test
Bytes: [B@38daa6a6`

Comment: @AndrewHassan [B@xx means byte[] at mem addr xx . you should do like this          byte[] b = new byte[]{1,2,3};
        System.out.println(b); // wrong
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));

Comment: Oh, I can't believe I missed that. I feel really dumb right now haha. Thanks for your help!